# How to multiply 2 matrices using Parallel.ForEach?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, task-parallel-library

There is a function that multiplies two matrices as usual

```
public IMatrix Multiply(IMatrix m1, IMatrix m2)
        {
            var resultMatrix = new Matrix(m1.RowCount, m2.ColCount);
            for (long i = 0; i < m1.RowCount; i++)
            {
                for (byte j = 0; j < m2.ColCount; j++)
                {
                    long sum = 0;
                    for (byte k = 0; k < m1.ColCount; k++)
                    {
                        sum += m1.GetElement(i, k) * m2.GetElement(k, j);
                    }

                    resultMatrix.SetElement(i, j, sum);
                }
            }

            return resultMatrix;
        }
```

This function should be rewritten using Parallel.ForEach Threading, I tried this way

```
public IMatrix Multiply(IMatrix m1, IMatrix m2)
        {
            // todo: feel free to add your code here

            var resultMatrix = new Matrix(m1.RowCount, m2.ColCount);
            
            Parallel.ForEach(m1.RowCount, row =>
            {
                for (byte j = 0; j < m2.ColCount; j++)
                {
                    long sum = 0;
                    for (byte k = 0; k < m1.ColCount; k++)
                    {
                        sum += m1.GetElement(row, k) * m2.GetElement(k, j);
                    }

                    resultMatrix.SetElement(row, j, sum);
                }
            });

            return resultMatrix;
        }
```

But there is an error with the type argument in the loop. How can I fix it?

Comment: `Parallel.ForEach` and `Parallel.For` do the same thing. The teacher may be asking for `ForEach` but would agree that `For` is a better choice here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use Parallel.For instead of Parallel.Foreach, that should let you keep the exact same body as the non-parallel version:

```
Parallel.For(0, m1.RowCount, i =>{
   ...
}
```

Note that only fairly large matrices will benefit from parallelization, so if you are working with 4x4 matrices for graphics, this is not the approach to take.

One problem with multiplying matrices is that you need to access one value for each row for one of the matrices in your innermost loop. This access pattern may be difficult to cache by your processor, causing lots of cache misses. So a fairly easy optimization is to copy an entire column to a temporary array and do all computations that need this column before reading the next. This lets all memory access be nice and linear and easy to cache. this will do more work overall, but better cache utilization easily makes it a win. There are even more cache efficient methods, but the complexity also tend to increase.

Another optimization would be to use [SIMD](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/hardware-intrinsics-in-net-core/), but this might require platform specific code for best performance, and will likely involve more work. But you might be able to find libraries that are already optimized.

But perhaps most importantly, **Profile your code**. It is quite easy to have simple things consume lot of time. You are for example using an interface, so if you may have a virtual method call for each memory access that cannot be inlined, potentially causing a severe performance penalty compared to a direct array access.

Comment: I should use exactly Parallel.ForEach, how can I rewrite it?

Comment: @Kurbanov27 there is no way for us to tell, since you do not show the `IMatrix` interface. And your requirement does not make much sense, for compute oriented code like matrix multiplication, using regular for-loops, parallel or otherwise, usually results in better and faster code.

Comment: This is because after that I should compare different approaches and make a unit test to find out the size when Parallel multiplication takes less time than the regular

Comment: @Kurbanov27 that is an even stronger argument for using `Parallel.For`, since that is a direct analogue for your outermost for-loop. That way your benchmark will actually compare apples to apples.

Comment: Ok, thank you sm. I will try now to create a method that creates two matrices of size N and check how much time it takes to multiply a matrix with MatricesMultiplier and MatricesMultiplierParallel.

Comment: @Kurbanov27 A triple loop like in your example should work for matrices of any size. So I'm not sure why you claim it is any more difficult than for 4x4 matrices. Or so you mean your matrix class is limited to 4x4?

Comment: Also note that the break-even point of parallelization may shift depending on the level of optimization and hardware. If you use SIMD and a cache efficient algorithm, you will need larger matrices to benefit from multiple threads.

Comment: I got it, sorry for bothering

Answer (score 0):

`ForEach` receives a collection, `IEnumerable` as the first argument and `m1.RowCount` is a number.
Probably `Parallel.For()` is what you wanted.